# Can't Understand De Moivre's Theorem Application: $\sin(3t) = 3\sin t - 4\sin^3t$

Tags: analysis, trigonometry

> Show that $\sin(3t) = 3\sin t - 4\sin^3t$ using De Moivre's Theorem.

I don't understand the given solution.

$$\begin{align}
\sin(3t) &= \Im(\cos^3t + 3i\cos^2 t\sin t - 3\cos t \sin^2 t - i\sin^3 t) \\
&= 3(1-\sin^2 t)\sin t - \sin^3 t \\
&= 3\sin t-4\sin^3t
\end{align}$$

How do they go from $\sin(3t)$ to $\Im(\cos^3 t + 3i \cos^2t\sin t - 3\cos t\sin^2 t - i\sin^3 t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't. That polynomial is $(\cos t + i\sin t)^3$. The point of de Moivre is that, because $e^{it}=\cos t + i\sin t$, the trivial-looking result $e^{int}=(e^{it})^n$ gives trigonometric formulae.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- Expand the polynomial $(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)^3$ out using the binomial theorem.  Separate the real parts and the imaginary parts.
- Use other trigonometric identities to put everything in terms of $\sin \theta.$